# A Documentary or Short film set in Medieval Europe about a king who impales enemies and a Scientist that gives electric shocks to corpses

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have been searching for this one for almost a decade now without any luck. I think this film was a European production. I don't exactly know when it was made but it was probably made in the late 90s or in the 2000s. It was like one of those historical films that you would expect would air on History Channel or BBC with some person narrating in the background. I remember two scenes:

1. Two or three men violently drag a man across an open field on the orders of their king. They then proceed to impale him by inserting a wooden post up his anus. They then lift the him up straight and the man dies as the post goes through his back. Quite disturbing.
2. Some scientist or a necromancer(not sure what) and performs some kind of experiment on a male corpse by giving it electric shocks. The corpse wriggles around as it is given a shock and its eyes go white. I'm thinking the scientist was trying to bring him back to life. However, the experiment fails and the scientist is apparently very distressed about it. He goes around knocking things around in the experiment room in frustration.

Also a minor thing I remember is that at the end of the documentary, the same ruthless king impales some priest after the priest informs him that he will go to Hell for his crimes. The king asks a young boy the same question and that is where it ends. The narrator then tells us that it is not known what the boy said we do know that the king spared his life.

The film is in English and is set in Northern Europe(the setting is very cloudy and cold, so I figured). According to what I think(and I might be wrong), the movie is about Vlad the Impaler but so far I haven't been able to find what it is.

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly it sounds like a movie that's combining Frankenstein and Dracula - my first thought was The League of Extraordinary Gentleman. The first person is a reference to Dracula - Vlad Dracula, who was also known as Vlad Tepes - which, translated, is Vlad *the impaler*. He got that nick name for impaling his enemies.